How to make the content of full calendar scrollable horizontally
I have a full calendar component using version ^6.1.8 version Angular 15 and I want to make the view of calendar scrollable at certain width p.s 500px because on mobile days look so thin.

I want the red box to be scrollable and the yellow part to stay the same, both come as a whole in this component.
<full-calendar *ngIf="calendarVisible" [options]="calendarOptions" #fullCalendar>
   <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
       <span>
        {{ arg.event.title }}
   </ng-template>
</full-calendar>

I tried adding dayMinWidth to the calendar options here
this.calendarOptions = {
      plugins: [
        interactionPlugin,
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        listPlugin,
      ],
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        right: ''
      },
      dayMinWidth:'200'
     ...other atttriburtes
      */
    };
   }


but it gives me this error: No ScrollGrid implementation
Is there any attribute to add that makes it scrollable horizontally at a certain width?

try using the plugin scroll grid

thank you, it works but it shows that I have no available license.

Then buy a license? Maybe this plugin only works with the paid version of this calendar.
